# Customize UIDocumentMenuViewController look

Tags: ios, document, icloud

Is it possible to customize the look of a UIDocumentMenuViewController instance, specifically the font? Our app uses a custom font throughout and the UIDocumentMenuViewController looks a little out of place. My gut is no, since the menu view is a UIRemoteView...

Comment: No, unfortunately not. I think, since this is handled remotely by the system, it's a black box. Hopefully they open it up for customization at some point.

Comment: I took a crack at customizing it, but limited success. They're using a UIAlertController to display the menu. Using [[UIView appearanceWhenContainedIn:UIAlertController.class] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]]

Comment: Ya, I was able to tweak a couple minor things as well, but nothing as far as fonts or anything like that, unfortunately...